# Special tags should render faithfully when using [tag:XXX] syntax

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta

You can use the syntax `[tag:navigation]` to typeset something that looks like a tag on a post, e.g. [navigation](/questions/tagged/navigation). However, certain tags render differently, e.g. the 'compulsory' tags discussion, feature-request, bug, etc., and the 'status' tags, e.g. status-completed. When using the `[tag:XXX]` syntax these display just the same as usual tags. Could we fix this?

Comment: For Meta tags, use `[meta-tag:tag-name]` - the special required and status tags get rendered correctly.